# Java code on Android Studio has errors saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'Button'" and the same thing for a TextView

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

Here is my strings.xml code for the button and text view.

```
<string name="calculate">Hitung</string>
<string name="result">Hasil</string>
```

Here is the Java part

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnCalculate;
private TextView tvResult;
```

Please let me know the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the views in the code? If not,in code part use in the top of the file:

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: Do I have to do it to the other views as well?

Comment: in every code file you are using the views, you have to import the views similar to this. If it helps, you can use import android.widget.*;  . Like this , you are importing all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't just import the libraries for Button and TextView Class in your .java file. Simply just move your type blinking cursor on word **Button** and hit `alt + enter` then from the dropdown menu select ***import***. Do same thing for **TextView**. Hope your problem solve.

Comment: There is no "import library", but there is "import class". I'm not sure that it's a class, but should I click it?

Comment: @petrusbagaskara sure

Comment: @petrusbagaskara Glad to help <3

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong,  you need to give the button an id as well, like

And in your activity you need to link it 
button button = FindViewById(R.id.button_id)

Check this as well, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button

Comment: I have given an id for the button as btn_calculate. Should I change it to btnCalculate (just like in the code)?

And I also have written the FindViewById thing under "protected void onCreate".

Comment: Hi, no, if you already added them it is fine as it. As the other guys told you, maybe you are missing the import of the libraries or the views.